# Как правильно выбрать groupId?

Tags: java, maven

Изучаю тему в Maven, где рассказывается как правильно обозначать координаты проекта, а именно groupId. Там написано, что:

*groupId - это группа, компания, команда, организация, проект или другая группа. Соглашение для идентификаторов групп заключается в том, что они начинаются с обратного доменного имени организации, создающей проект.*

А что, если у меня нет сайта и я создаю проект одна. То как правильно выбрать groupId в этом случае?

Answer (score 3):

Можете считать, что это просто уникальный идентификатор.

Обычно делают так: доменное имя (com, org, ru, ...) + точка + ваши имя фамилия + точка + название проекта. Естественно всё на английском без пробелов.

Comment: типа ru.ivan.ivanov.myproject?

Comment: Да, можно так. Я бы сделал ru.ivanivanov.myproject

Comment: Часто вообще оставляют первую букву имени + фамилия, вместо полного имени + фамилия

Answer (score 2):

Если вы создаёте проект для себя и не будете его выкладывать в общий репозиторий библиотек, то абсолютно неважно какой groupId вы зададите, можете использовать com.example, com.google, com.mysupersite (в общем всё, что придёт в голову).

Если же планируете выкладывать в локальный или приватный репозиторий, то желательно указать что-то вменяемое, представьте, какое доменное имя могло бы быть у вашего сайта и создайте groupId с ним. Его не надо будет регистрировать, просто подумайте, каким оно было бы.

Если вы планируете опубликовывать библиотеку в открытые репозитории, вроде mavenCentral, то там надо смотреть на политику публикации. Некоторые требуют подтверждения прав на домен, в этом случае вам действительно понадобится зарегистрировать такой домен. Однако в есть открытые репозитории, которые не требуют подтверждать права (например на Github Packages), там вы можете тоже придумать свой groupId, который в будущем возможно будет вашим.

Answer (score 1):

Если проект не будешь выкладывать никуда, то и смысл ему вообще корректный `groupId` давать? Просто напиши что-нибудь для себя, все что угодно.

Если все же проект будет выкладываться или показываться где-нибудь / кому-нибудь, то необходимо, конечно же, все правильно указать, а именно: `ru.yourprojectname`. Тут нет разницы, какой домен, `ru` или `su`, `com`, `org`. На твой выбор.